# Saving and Retrieving a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This might seem like a beginner question, but it has me stumped.  I have a User model and a Location model.  A location belongs to a user and a user has many locations.  I have locations stored as a nested resource in my routes file.

Here's the create function in my LocationsController file:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @location = @user.locations.build(params[:location])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user }
        format.js { 
          @locations = @user.locations
          render 'create' 
        }
      else
        format.html { render @user }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('table#locations').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@locations)) %>");
```

_location.html.erb:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= location.user.name %></td>
  <td><%= location.created_at %></td>
  <td><%= location.longitude %></td>
  <td><%= location.latitude %></td>
</tr>
```

Saving to the database using AJAX works without a problem.  However, when the record is retrieved, the last row of the returned table only includes the user name.  The created_at, longitude and latitude are not displayed.  If I refresh the page then they are displayed.  Does anybody have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks.

**Update**

I reversed the order of the models and it's still the bottom entry that isn't printing.  My guess is it's something to do with the views and not the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be arising when you initialize your @locations variable in the controller for the AJAX response. You save the new location, but perhaps the @user object doesn't notice. Instead of

```
@locations = @user.locations
```

try

```
@locations = Location.where(:user_id => @user)
```

or something like that, which will guarantee that you're pulling the locations from the database.

It's a guess!

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but it didn't work.  Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: well, can you log the contents of @locations to the console/log from the controller? You have to determine if the data is actually there. If it is, then you know it's an issue with your view (which I doubt because your view code seems pretty simple).

Comment: Well you're right.  When I log the data from the controller, the last entry is missing its data.  It reads #<Location id: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>.  The weird part is I validate the presence of longitude and latitude in my Location model.

Comment: Thinking about it, I also can't figure out why that entry is showing up under @user.locations, when it's clearly missing a user_id.

Comment: have you made sure that params[:location] is correct and complete?

Comment: There's my problem.  The location data in params was incomplete.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting your user record from the database before saving the new location it might not be retrieving the new location. Perhaps a call `user.reload` before rendering the view. Or waiting to do `User.find` until after you've saved the location.